# LeanFT 15.0.2 is not identifying Web Elements in MSEdge

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, leanft

We are using LeanFT with C# to automate my Sample Web Application which is heavily used in IE only. Since microsoft is ending support with IE, we are moving the tests to MSEdge where there are certain components which will be loaded in Browser if and only if I enable the EDGE browser to use **IE server mode**

Now once the IE Server mode is enabled on MSEdge, the browser is launching and the URL is being navigated. But when we enable Object spy to identify an element for my OR file, the browser view window is completely shown as IEserverWindow ( i.e Standard Desktop Windows ) and the web elements can't be identified

- I had enabled UFT extension on browser by manually loading unpacked extension on Edge
- Added the NativeMessgaingHost key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to upgrade to UFT 2021

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2021_R1/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Chrome_Chromium_FF_Limitations.htm#IE